# Setup SSL certificate on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS machine:

```
64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Node.js
```

- How to generate CSR code in this kind of controlled-environment?
- How to I setup a SSL certificate on a load-balanced environment?

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: OK linked: http://serverfault.com/questions/772632/setup-ssl-certificate-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: Are you using us-east-1 region, or another region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SSH into any of the servers in your environment and generate a CSR from there. It really doesn't matter where you generate the CSR from.

You install the SSL onto the ELB itself, instead of each EC2 instance. If you search you will find plenty of tutorials on that.